# atomic load/save on c struct (gcc) questions

Tags: c, gcc, struct, atomic, gcc6

trying my luck in making lock-free singly linked list implementation.

```
typedef _Atomic struct _node
  {
    void *data;
    struct _node *next;
  } Node;
```

does this make all members of struct with _Atomic atomic as well?

```
void add_head ( Linked_list* list, void* data )
{
  if ( debugging )
  {
      printf ( "%s\n", __func__ );
  }
  Node *node = ( Node* ) calloc ( 1, sizeof (Node ) );
  //init_node_mutex(node);
  //lock_node_mutex(node);
  atomic_exchange ( &node->next, NULL );
  atomic_exchange ( &node->data, data );

  if ( list->head == NULL )
  {
      Node* the_tail = atomic_load ( &list->tail );
      //  lock_node_mutex ( the_tail );
      atomic_exchange ( &node->next, NULL );
      atomic_compare_exchange_weak ( &list->tail, the_tail, node );

      //unlock_node_mutex ( the_tail );

  }
  else
  {

      Node* the_next = atomic_load ( &node->next );
      // lock_node_mutex ( the_next );
      atomic_compare_exchange_weak ( &node->next, the_next, list->head );
      // unlock_node_mutex ( the_next );
  }

  Node* the_head = atomic_load ( & list->head );
  //lock_node_mutex ( the_head );
  atomic_store ( &list->head, node );
  atomic_store ( &list->current, node );
  //unlock_node_mutex ( the_head );
  //unlock_node_mutex(node);
  atomic_fetch_add ( &list->size, 1 );
}
```

are usages are atomic_load and atomic_store correct?

Comment: In the C11 standard, section §6.5.2.3 **Structure and union members** (for the `.` and `->` operators) ¶5 says _Accessing a member of an atomic structure or union object results in undefined
behavior.97)_ and footnote 97 says _For example, a data race would occur if access to the entire structure or union in one thread conflicts
with access to a member from another thread, where at least one access is a modification. Members
can be safely accessed using a non-atomic object which is assigned to or from the atomic object._

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I debated whether to post this as a "comment" or an "answer," but I'm going to go for broke here.

My instincts are rather screaming at me that "it really doesn't matter if the individual operations that you're performing are, or are not, "atomic," because you are executing many operations in a row in order to accomplish what you are ultimately trying to do. Even if those individual steps are "atomic," the operation as a whole is not.

An "atomic" operation is one that uses *specialized machine instructions,* such as the `LOCK` prefix on the x86 or "compare-and-swap" instructions on big-iron, to perform *a single operation* such that no other *CPU (or core)* will interfere with that *single* operation.

But, you can't do what you're trying to do in "a single instruction," atomic or not.

Therefore, I cordially recommend that you now **abandon** your present course, put those "mutex" calls back in, and remove the "atomics." Your code (and, all such code as this ...) needs those mutexes. In my opinion, you are chasing a white rabbit down a blind alley.

*(And incidentally,* "mutex" operations sometimes make very good use of those "atomic instructions," so they're probably a good bit more efficient than you might fear.)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @MikeRobinson's comment, I would add that while your code is "lock-free" in the sense that it does not contain any explicit use of locks, it is now (somewhat ironically) no longer thread-safe. Writing lock-free code is enormously difficult. I recommend reading through [this](http://preshing.com/20120612/an-introduction-to-lock-free-programming/) to get a bird's-eye view of the world, and then reading [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123973376) to get some details or Chapter 7 of [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988770) (it's in C++). You can always go look through the source of [Boost.LockFree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/lockfree.html) for inspiration.